# how would you prove that $f(x) = x^n$ is $C^\infty$ function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

$f(x)=x^n$ is a function that is infinitely differentiable and so it is a $C^\infty$ function.
How would you prove it? I am new to this and not sure how to do it..

Comment: What do you know so far?

Comment: So far I've learnt $\epsilon -\delta$ proving and some basic topology and also taylor expansion and maclaurin series in this chapter

Comment: Question just asked to show that $f(x)=x^n$is a $C^\infty$ function, should I just write $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-i)!} x^(n-i)$

Comment: Use induction e.g.: if a function $f$ has a derivative $f'$ that's $C^\infty$ then $f$ is in $C^\infty$ too. A $C^\infty$ function need *not* be a power series, but all convergent power series are $C^\infty$ on their domain. Beware!

Comment: But then how would you say that $f'$ which is $nx^{n-1}$ a $C^\infty$ function? Don't I have to prove that too?

Comment: You can prove that every polynomial is differentiable and its derivative is also a polynomial. This allows to prove, almost immediately by mathematical induction, that every polynomial is of $C^k$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots$, and therefore, of $C^{\infty}$.